# How to create a 'bridge' docker network equivilate to the default bridge network, on a different VLAN

Tags: docker-network

Im attempting to create a docker network that is a 'bridged' network, the same as the default docker `docker`/`bridge` network, but on a different VLAN, so containers assigned to the VLANed bridge network have a bridged ip, eg 172.20.0.5, but the traffic will go over a different interface, ie eth100, rather than eth0. Seems simple, but I cant find any resources on how to achieve this, everything points to using the mac/ipvlan driver. Heres a basic diagram of what im trying to achieve (ipv4+ipv6):

(pretty sure this is how the default docker0 network works)

| Interface | IP Subnet | Docker/Bridge Network | Docker IP Subnet | Containers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| eth0 | 192.168.1.0/24 | docker0 | 172.20.x.x/xx | 172.20.0.4 |
|  | 2404:xxx:xxxx::0/64 |  | <whatever ipv6 address> | <ipv6 address> |
| eth100 | 192.168.100.0/24 | docker100 | 172.30.x.x/xx | 172.30.0.4 |
|  | 2404:xxx:xxxx:100::0/64 |  | <whatever ipv6 address> | <ipv6 address> |

I have tried to use brctl to create another bridge network called docker100, but then when I create a docker network to parent the docker100 network, it overwrites the IP, also had issues with the bridge interface trying to get the same ip as the 'master' interface, causing IP overlaps. the network did also not persist over a reboot.